# Command line print call from batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, printing

Using Windows 7, I am trying to print a HCFA file via dropping the .txt file onto a batch icon in my desktop.  The printer port is a typical TCP/IP.  I have already added  to regedit because of an invalic UNC path.

I have tried many combinations of the print function such as:

```
print %1 - Displays the file is bring printed but is not printing.
print /D:"HP LaserJet 3055 PCL5" %1 - "printer name" - unable to initialize device
print /D:00.0.0.000 %1 - unableto initialize device
```

Nothing seems to work correctly.  Are there any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using printer pooling I was able to add the printer to the default port and had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Printers in Control panel and open the properties for the printer you want and click Hardware. The UNC path shown here is the value you want in the /D: parameter